# How to setup sbt/scala/play multi-module project which will work fine with Intellij scala plugin

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I'm setting up a new multi-module project (sbt/scala/play/IntejjiJ) and I would like to have two things:

1. A multi-module project with one build.sbt file with this layout

```
project
 |_Dependencies.scala
 |_plugin.sbt
modules
 |_adapters
   |_api (Play REST API)
     |_app
     |_conf
   |_infrastructure (bare bone scala)
     |-src/main/scala
 |_application (bare bone scala)
   |_src/main/scala
 |_domain (bare bone scala)
   |_src/main/scala
 |_query (bare bone scala)
   |_src/main/scala 
build.sbt
```

2. I would like to be able to use IntelliJ Play2 plugin (Run/Debug Configuration)

So far, I'm getting the following error when I run the application using Play2 Run/Debug Configuration settings:

```
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
[error]     at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
[error] (Compile / bgRun) No main class detected.
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Jun 1, 2019 11:21:31 PM
```

Here is what I have so far:

build.sbt

```
import Dependencies._

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "com.borkke.rally",
  version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
  scalaVersion := "2.12.8",
  scalacOptions := Seq(
    "-deprecation",
    "-feature"
  ),
  libraryDependencies ++= CommonDependencies
)


//PROJECTS
lazy val rally = project
  .in(file("."))
  .aggregate(domain,application,query,api,infrastructure)
  .settings(
    name := "rally",
    commonSettings,
    publishArtifact := false
  )

lazy val api = project
  .in(file("modules/adapter/api"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .dependsOn(domain,application,query,infrastructure)
  .settings(
    name := "api",
    commonSettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= ApiDependencies
  )

lazy val domain = project
  .in(file("modules/domain"))
  .settings(
    name := "domain",
    commonSettings
  )

lazy val application = project
  .in(file("modules/application"))
  .dependsOn(domain)
  .settings(
    name := "application",
    commonSettings
  )

lazy val query = project
  .in(file("modules/query"))
  .settings(
    name := "query",
    commonSettings
  )

lazy val infrastructure = project
  .in(file("modules/adapter/infrastructure"))
  .dependsOn(domain)
  .settings(
    name := "infrastructure",
    commonSettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= InfrastructureDependencies
  )
```

Dependencies.scala

```
import sbt._
import play.sbt.PlayImport._

object Dependencies {
  private val scalatest_version = "3.0.5"
  private val v2Db_version = "1.4.198"
  private val logback_version = "5.3"
  private val play_version = "2.7.2"
  private val cassandra_driver_version = "3.7.1"
  private val postgresql_driver_version = "42.2.5"
  private val kafka_client_version = "2.2.0"

  private val scalatest = "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % scalatest_version
  private val scalatic = "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % scalatest_version
  private val h2Db = "com.h2database" %% "h2" % v2Db_version
  private val logback = "net.logstash.logback" % "logstash-logback-encoder" % logback_version
  private val play = "com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % play_version
  private val cassandra_driver = "com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-extras" % cassandra_driver_version
  private val postgresql_driver = "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % postgresql_driver_version
  private val kafka_client = "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % kafka_client_version

  lazy val CommonDependencies = Seq(scalatic, scalatest % "test", logback, guice)

  lazy val InfrastructureDependencies = Seq(cassandra_driver, postgresql_driver, kafka_client)

  lazy val ApiDependencies = Seq(play)
}
```

plugin.sbt

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

//wrapper around play console.
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.7.2")

//dependency resolver. parallel downloads
addSbtPlugin("io.get-coursier" % "sbt-coursier" % "1.1.0-M11")

//shows available updates. dependencyUpdates || dependencyUpdatesReport
addSbtPlugin("com.timushev.sbt" % "sbt-updates" % "0.4.0")

//create one jar for application.
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.5")

//linter
addSbtPlugin("org.wartremover" % "sbt-wartremover" % "2.2.1")
```

Run Configuration
[image]

Comment: If I understand you don't have a problem with IntelliJ, you have a problem with Play not finding your `application.conf` wchis is probable one of many difficulties about Play Framework plugin configuration: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/SBTSubProjects - try running `sbt "show resourceDirectory"` to check what are the resource directories in your project.

Comment: This listed all resource directories from all other modules but the one that has Play application ("api" module).

Comment: I was toying around a little bit more and I ended up moving `.enablePlugins(PlayScala)` to the api module... and after that when I run the app using cli command `sbt api/run` it works fine. But using scala plugin, it does not. It throws this error:

```
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
[error]  at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
[error] (Compile / bgRun) No main class detected.
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Jun 1, 2019 10:44:14 PM

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Here is my gist with current set up:
https://gist.github.com/borkke/3a6c69cb9e76fea554451ca39c1002ed

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the intellij run-configuration

Comment: I added a screenshot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider changing the build structure such that `api` is moved to become the root project like so:

```
lazy val api = project
  .in(file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .aggregate(domain,application,query,infrastructure)
  .dependsOn(domain,application,query,infrastructure)
  .settings(
    name := "api",
    commonSettings,
    publishArtifact := false,
    libraryDependencies ++= ApiDependencies
  )
```

This means `modules/adapters/api` is moved to the project root directory, and `lazy val root = ...` is deleted from `build.sbt`, such that the directory structure becomes

```
.
├── app
│   ├── controllers
│   ├── filters
│   ├── services
│   └── views
├── build.sbt
├── conf
│   ├── application.conf
│   ├── logback.xml
│   └── routes
├── modules
│   ├── adapters
│   │   └── infrastructure
│   ├── application
│   │   ├── src
│   ├── domain
│   │   ├── src
│   └── query
│       ├── src
├── project
│   ├── Dependencies.scala
│   ├── build.properties
│   ├── plugins.sbt
│   ├── project
│   └── target
```

This should make the `Play 2 App` run configuration work again, although make sure Play compiler is enabled by checking:

```
Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Play2 | Compiler | Use Play 2 compiler for this project
```

If preferring to keep the original structure, then as a workaround, try defining `sbt Task` run configuration instead of `Play 2 App`, as documented in official [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/IDE#IntelliJ-IDEA):

1. `Run | Edit Configurations`
2. Click on the `+` to add a new configuration
3. Choose `sbt Task`
4. In the `tasks` input box put `api/run`
5. Apply changes and select OK.

Comment: Thanks Mario for the detailed answer. I'm currently using that workaround you mentioned. Anyway, it's too bad that web framework/tool forces you to structure your application in a specific way.

Answer (score 2):

**Background context, feel free to skip:**

The most recent version of Intellij runs into route compile issues when using `sbt task` run configs as defined on the Play2 documentation. So I wanted to use the `Play 2 App` run config as an alternative.

While Mario's solution works it isn't an option for those who cannot move base directory. Trying to use the `Play 2 App` run config results in a `No main class detected` similar to what Aleksandar experienced in the comments of the opening question.

### Solution

To use `Play 2 App` run configs you have to:

1. Specify projects in `build.sbt` as you would normally.
2. Specify the Play2 module and the project uri to the project with your `build.sbt`. Unless altered in step 1, this will be the Play2 default: Project name and project root respectively.

   Setting in question found here:

   `File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Play2`

   As seen in the screenshot below, I also check `Use Play 2 compiler for this project`

   [image: Project uri defined in intellij settings]
3. Create a `Play 2 App` run configuration and specify the `Play 2 module` as the module with your main class method.

   Debug port should be the one specified in your settings for your breakpoint listener. No need to change by default.

   [image: Run config definition]
4. Run your newly created run configuration. Log output should look similar to that of running sbt via bash. Example below.

   [image: Server starting from play 2 app]

If it's failing to start, ensure that you don't have duplicate declarations of JVM params across default settings in Scala and JVM.